# Android copy/paste content

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, clipboard

I am trying to copy content via clipboard to other applications on android. This is how i put my content:// uri string into clipboard. At that uri I have an image.

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "image", contentUri);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

Am I doing something wrong, or are applications like skype, messaging, twitter not resolving the content as when I paste I always only get text?

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? you mean string image ??

Comment: what do u mean by `not resolving the content`

Comment: Are you expecting , when you paste this content through clipboard manager 
instead of seeing the uri string , you should be able to see image for that uri ???

Comment: RenuYadav: Yes. 

Now it seems to me that this is not possible and share is the way to go?

@AtefHares i expected these apps to get the image that resides on given Uri.